# Using boundingRectWithSize for iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift

I came across boundingRectWithSize while I was watching some iOS tutorials. I have read the documentation but would like some experts to elaborate on the topic, specifically the following code.

```
let rect = NSString(string: name).boundingRectWithSize(CGSizeMake(frame.width, 1000), options: NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesFontLeading.union(NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesLineFragmentOrigin), attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(14)], context: nil)
```